# How to test an Intent in a none Activity class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-intent, android-espresso

I am trying to create a Class which creates an Intent and starts a new Activity, now i have a Problem with testing it.

```
private static final String TAG = IntentToActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// ----------------
// START VARIABLES
// ----------------
private String fqClassName;
private Intent intentToActivity;
private Context context;
// --------------
// END VARIABLES
// --------------

/**
 * Constructor sets needed variables, creates and performs intent
 * @param fqClassName full qualified class name to intent to
 * @param context context of the current using activity
 */
public IntentToActivity(String fqClassName, Context context) {
    this.fqClassName = fqClassName;
    this.context = context;

    performIntent();
}

/**
 * Creates and performs intent
 *
 * IMPORTANT: Intent must be referented in the manifest of the application use following code:
 * <intent-filter>
 *      <action android:name="com.example.exampleapplication.ExampleClass" />
 *      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 * </intent-filter>
 */
private void performIntent() {
    if (fqClassName != null) {
        try {
            intentToActivity = new Intent(fqClassName);
            context.startActivity(intentToActivity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "performIntent error: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

My androidTest

public class IntentToActivityTest {
    @Rule
   public IntentsTestRule intentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(IntentToActivity.class);

```
@Test
public void newActivityLaunchingTest() {

    Intents.intended(IntentMatchers.hasComponent("com.example.mmal.example.auth.IntentToActity2Example"));

}
```

My first question, how to start an intent for the test
My second, how to implement an non activity class as rule

currenr error Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:467)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:354)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:525)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2108)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.motionminers.mmal.test/com.motionminers.mmal.backend.mv.IntentToActivity }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:447)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.access$101(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:98)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:443)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:440)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not test Android classes. This is because mock it, is a very heavy and hard work.

In MVP architecture, you can pass the Intent data (String for example) to the Presenter, so he can analyze this data and tells to View (Activity) how to behave.

So, in this example scenario, in the constructor you can pass any String data and test if Presenter calls a certain View methods.

Comment: So you think i just should unit test the Inputs? Not the Intent?

Comment: Yes, if Intent have a boolean in their data, you will test entire Intent functionality? No, you are only interested in boolean value, so you will play with this boolean value.

Comment: So Calling class and return the Intent to the unittest to check if its true... sounds interesting. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Oh... No no, you test class do not contains any reference to Android classes.
Imagine you have a ExamplePresenter(boolean isLegacyModeEnabled), so in your test class can create a test method to verify how view methods call when is true or false that flag. 
In the Activity implementation you will have:
....
presenter = new ExamplePresenter(Intent.getData(flag));

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more specific ? How do i need to test this case?

Comment: Sorry, i edit my last comment, please read it and if you have doubts comment again!

Comment: Okay if i get it right i should create a method in an Activity which calls the Intent and returns a boolean value back, right?

Comment: Yes, you delegate in Presenter the responsibility to evaluate the boolean. The Activity only pass this value to Presenter.
Please take care about this implementation is in a MVP architecture model!

Comment: so in my case presenter = new Activity().presenter(string)... Presenter gives me the value i intented to

Comment: Here are a example of MVP:
https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-you-hand-dirty-with-mvp-model-view-presenter-eab5b5c16e42

The Presenter calls View methods (Activity). 
The View only exposes methods like:
showLoading(bool), showTitle(String), showButton(bool)
The Presenter exposes methods like:
onButtonClicked(), onCloseDialog(), onTextChange(String)

Comment: In Presenter constructor you got the data of Presenter needs, so in this case you pass the Intent data, e.g.: String.